# Support for landscape mode under iOS 8

Tags: bug, ios-app

Using version 1.0.1 of the app on an iPhone 6 and iOS 8.0 the keyboard is not drawn in landscape mode.

See attached image for the test cases:

- sign in buttons are extremely hard to use

[image]

- since this happens in the weather app from Apple, I'm not certain that this isn't an SDK error or something the devs of the iOS app can remedy with code changes or if Apple will fix this with an iOS update.

[image]

Comment: Don't worry, it is off-road mode. :D

Comment: We will be adding landscape support in the next update of the app, so this *should* be fixed then

Comment: @ArieLitovsky I don't get landscape for log in screen on 1.1.0.110 but I do see some partial support for it implemented there already. Is there any goal to get a fix for iPhone users out to the app store or are you holding all updates until iPad is ready as well?

Comment: @bmike The landscape login is currently only turned on for the iPhone 6+. I'm not sure we would release a fix until iPad is ready, unless it's something really critical.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Thanks! I figured as much from the announcement to rate the June version of the app in the store. I'm really excited with the changes for iPad so I'm eager for that to get finished and then released.